# .json file not in main bundle error Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am using Landmarks tutorial for one of my projects https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views

I am having hard time decoding .json file
It shows this
`Fatal error: Couldn't find landmarkData.json in main bundle.: file`

I checked my **Build Phase** and **Copy Bundle Resources** and file appears there.

```
let landmarkData: [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.") //New Error here Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Which folder do you open?  If you open 'StartingPoint,' you have everything you need.

Comment: Try to delete your app from device/simulator, make clean, rebuild and install again, sometimes it helps to refresh resources.

Comment: Thank you @iUrii, it helped but it showed new error Thread 1: ```EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)``` on the line that I commented above in the code

Comment: @ElTomato I am using that as a reference for my own project and following the exact same steps

Comment: I delete the file landmarkData.json and add again and works !

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on Target Membership for Landmarks within the file landmarkData.json.

Click on landmarkData.json -> Show File Inspector -> Look for ‘Target Membership’ then tick on 'Landmarks’. This will ensure that the JSON file is included in your app bundle and can be located and decoded correctly by the JSONDecoder().

Answer (score -2):

I dragged and dropped one more time the landMark.json file in the Resources folder in the tree and it worked.